# Spring Cloud Config encrypted property as default value

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

Having application.yml like this:

```
foo.bar: '{cipher}aaa'
```

works OK.

I'd like to use the encrypted value as a default only. So something like:

```
foo.bar: '${xyz:{cipher}aaa}'
```

This however doesn't work, as the `{cipher}aaa` part is not recognized as encrypted.

How should I fix it?

Comment: IIRC the `{cipher}` bit is only recognized at the beginning of a property. Maybe try setting `foo.bar.default={cipher}aaa` and then foo.bar: '${xyz:${foo.bar.default}}'?

Comment: @spencergibb works!, please add as answer, to get proper credit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `{cipher}` bit is only recognized at the beginning of a property. Try setting

```
foo.bar.default: {cipher}aaa
foo.bar: '${xyz:${foo.bar.default}}'
```

Comment: alternatively what also worked was encrypting the whole property: `${xyz:foo}` and keeping that one as '{cipher}...', but that hides the property name and it's therefore not very practical. moreover if exposing the property name as a comment, it could be a security risk, as part of the encrypted value would be exposed